# I Want To Send The Player To A Restart Screen After Colliding With A Spike

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where when the player collides with a spike, it's supposed to switch scenes.

I have the player tagged player, I have box colliders on the player and the spike.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "EnemySpike(Clone)")
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene("Death");

        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't give any errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add the Scene you want to load to the build settings?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the LoadScene is never getting called because in your if statement, your comparing the GameObject's tag with the GameObject's name. You could either change `collision.gameObject.tag` to `collision.gameObject.name` or change the string to the objects actual tag. Also, it is good practice to log when the collision happens so that you can confirm the collision is detected. To do this just use `Debug.Log("Collided With Spike");`

Comment: The scene is in the build settings but it's still not working. Here's my new code.  
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
       
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "EnemySpike(Clone)")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collided With Spike");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Death");
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: The problem is most likely the if statement condition is not being satisfied. Do you see "Collided With Spike" printed into the console when you collide with a spike? If you don't that means it's not executing.The SceneManager.LoadScene doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: No I don't see the "Collided With Spike"

Comment: That means you collision isn't being detected. (The if statement is not being satisfied or the OnCollisionEnter isn't being called at all.) Check out this video for a tutorial on collision. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter

Comment: thanks, I watched the video but im still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Well, it could be that your GameObject isn't detecting collision at all. To rule this out, you could put a Debug.Log("Collision Detected") Before the If statement. This means that it will run any time the GameObject collides with an object. First try that out and see if that gets logged out.

Comment: ya its still not logging anything

Comment: That means your OnCollisionEnter is not being called (Nothing is colliding). Please make sure both collding objects have Colliders on them and Neither are not set to IsTrigger

Comment: They both have box colliders and neither are set to trigger

Comment: Double check and make sure that they're actually colliding because according to the script, nothing is being detected as colliding. That's about the best advice I can give.

Answer (score 0):

in order for a collision to be detected at least on of the objects must have a rigidbody. colliders alone wont work.

i run into this all the time. you can do `Print("Collided");` to see if your collision is going off at all. i bet its not. you need to add a `RigidBody`

if they both have rigid bodies, try using ontrigger enter instead, and set the spike collider to istrigger.

Comment: They both have rigidbody